# SHORTINIT and sessions

Tags: ajax, session

Is it possible to use SHORTINIT for AJAX called php file and use a Wordpress shared $_SESSION global in it?

I have this thus far:

```
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
define('SHORTINIT', true);

require 'wp-load.php';

$_SESSION...
```

...and it really made that file load in a snap, but with SHORTINIT i can't seem to retrieve that file's $_SESSION variables in Wordpress.
Commenting it out enables session sharing.

Comment: WP core doesn't use sessions, how exactly it is implemented in your case?

Comment: I'm using 'init' wordpress function in functions.php to  session_start. And that seems to initilize it in plain php also, via wp-load.php.
I should have also mentioned that this wordpress is installed in subfolder and plain php ajax file is in the root of the subfolder, alongside wp-load.php.